# how to show textbox dynamically in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

i want to show textbox in asp.net dynamically how it is possible in asp.net using c#

Comment: dynamically related to what? There's probably some condition that must be met to display it. It would be easier for us to pride some code if we knew what kind of condition is it. Is it a postback, is it an event or something completely different...

Comment: Based on John Gietzen's answer compared to mine, I'd say the question is unclear.  Do you want to dynamically add a textbox, or do you have a textbox that you want to show and hide dynamically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is just one text box, you can use the `Visible` property.

If you want to show a list of text boxes, use an `asp:Repeater` or similar.

Comment: +1 - If you interpreted the question correctly, then these are good answers.

Answer (score 1):

The instructions from MSDN are here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyt0fzt1.aspx